# System IO DirectoryInfo

Tags: powershell, database-restore

I just try to restore SQL backup to my restore server and I wrote script to do it but I get this error on my PowerShell console:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:39 char:1
+ $dbRestoreLog.LogicalFileName = $dbname + "_Log"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Well without showing some code it is difficult to help but I guess you are trying to add a string to an instance of System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Comment: You really need to post your code that's generating the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error shown, `$dbname` is obviously a `DirectoryInfo` object.

My guess it that you retrieved it through `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`.

If you want the `LogicalFileName` property to be the name of the `$dbname` folder with the string `"_Log"` appended, do:

```
$dbRestoreLog.LogicalFileName = $dbname.Name + "_Log"
```

---

Alternatively have PowerShell implicitly convert `$dbname` to a string by placing it inside double-quotes (`DirectoryInfo.ToString()` defaults to the `Name` property anyways):

```
$dbRestoreLog.LogicalFileName = "$dbname" + "_Log"
```

You could similarly use the `-f` string format operator:

```
$dbRestoreLog.LogicalFileName = '{0}_Log' -f $dbname
```